# 301 Redirect with nginx

Tags: nginx, permalinks

I moved my website URLs from this form:

```
https://example.com/category/sub-category/post-url
https://example.com/category/post-url
```

to this form:

```
https://example.com/post-url
```

And I would like to set up nginx redirection so that I don't lose the visitors going through old URLs.

I have found the regex that I need to use, which is simply `([^\/]+$)` (Takes all text after the last slash). But how can I set it up to use with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

In your server block entry you need to add:

```
server {
  ...
  # Your match:
  rewrite ^\/[^\/]+\/(.*) /$1 redirect;
  # Probably a better regex (I cannot test)
  # rewrite ^\/.*\/([^\/.]*)$ /$1 redirect;
  ...
}
```

`redirect` will give a 302 status, if you want a permanent move (which is [dangerous](https://jacquesmattheij.com/301-redirects-a-dangerous-one-way-street/)), then use `permanent` (301).  The regex mostly matches yours (although in practice I don't think it'll do what you want.. you need it to greedily match all but the last slash, I've added an alternative which you might want to run through the [Nginx tester](https://www.nginx.com/blog/regular-expression-tester-nginx/)), with a grouping match `(.*)` which is then referenced in the redirect as `$1`

### Updates for css/js/jpg/gif/png

*This is getting hacky* but since your post-urls don't appear to include a dot (`.`) we can filter the group-match to exclude dots, which leads to any URL ending in `file.ext` from *not* matching.

Using a [regex tester](https://regex101.com/) on `^\/.*\/([^\/.]*)$`, we can find reasonable accuracy (without actual details of what you have):

**Matching:**

```
/category/sub-category/post-url
/category/post-url
```

**Not matching:**

```
/images/blog.jpg #no match
/css/main.css #no match
/js/app.js
/favicon.ico
```

However, if your post-urls can include dots, this won't work.  Further if you have any static files that don't include dots - this won't work (you'll have to be far more specific in the regex about URLs that do/don't match)

Comment: Both broke my site. The CSS/Javascript can no longer load.

Comment: You didn't specify needing either of those in your question! Since you *don't* have extensions on your articles, and I'm assuming style, images and JS are in files with extensions (`.css`, `.jpg`, `.gif`, `.png`, `.js`) I've blocked dot on the group match - this is a bit of a hack

Comment: CSS/JS now loads, but not images. And also, posts are not loading (It redirects everything always to the homepage example.com).

Answer (score -1):

easiest way to do this is the .htaccess file. just create a textfile called .htaccess (no .txt at the end!). with following line:

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

import that to the nginx.config

Otherwise:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name old url;
    return 301 $scheme://new url;
}
```

Comment: nginx does not support .htaccess file. Your answer is totally unrelated to my question.

Comment: not directly but you can import the .htaccess to the nginx.conf